# Sum of a, b, and c without counting doublet values?

Tags: python

I am practicing Python on CodingBat. In there, a question is:

> Given 3 int values, a b c, return their sum. However, if one of the values is the same as another of the values, it does not count towards the sum.

And my answer is:

```
def lone_sum(a, b, c):
  if a==b:
   return c
  elif a==c:
   return b
  elif b==c:
   return a
  elif a==b and a==c:
   return 0
  else:
   return a+b+c
```

But when executing it's showing OK except in one case. That is `def long_sum(3,3,3)`. But when I write `if a==b and a==c` in first check then it is showing that all are OK.

Why this is occurring? Why do I need to write `elif a==b and a==c` in the first check?

Comment: Hint: if `a == b` is true, no other condition is tested, including `a == b and a == c`. Reorder.

Comment: that's great ! understood now !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` and `elif` statements are executed in order, and only if one of the earlier ones hasn't been true. The very first check sees that `a` and `b` are equal, and returns `c`. If there are cases where `a` and `b` are equal where you don't want to return `c`, you need to catch these first.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `c` immediately in this case, since `a == b` is satisfied. You should reorder your tests from most specific to least specific.

Answer (score 0):

just a way more pythonic : work with more than 3 args and with 1 if:

```
def lone_sum(*args):
    return sum(i for i in args if args.count(i) == 1)
```

sum take an iterable as only argument and make the sum of them all.

i make a generator, which is an itarable, with

```
i for i in args if args.count(i) == 1
```

it just give all element of args which apear only once in the list

Comment: would you please explain it ?

Answer (score 0):

try this, not very efficient but gets the work done.

```
def lone_sum(a, b, c):
  
  if a==b==c:
    return 0
  elif a==b:
    return c
  elif b==c:
    return a
  elif c==a:
    return b
  elif a!=b!=c:
    return a+b+c
```